# Redirecting website 3 language to static page for every url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to make my website in 3 language EN, AR , FR

My goal is redirect urls as following:
http://example.com/ - > to http://example.com/index.php?lang=en
(Because no language is specified and no page so redirect to index page with default language EN)

http://example.com/ar -> http://example.com/index.php?lang=ar

and for different pages i want the following
http://example.com/en/news/something-to-write - > http://example.com/news.php?lang=en&alias=something-to-write

i want this rewriting to be effective in /ar , /en , /fr , and also when no language specified

i want to view all pages

i dont want my css , images , and js folders to be affected so when user asks for 
http://example.com/fr/css/style.css it return to http://example.com/css/style.css

my code is not working well

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(assets|css|fonts|js|panel|rev)($|/) - [L]
# Force English on homepage no url 
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?lang=en
# English Homepage
RewriteRule ^en/?$ index.php?lang=en
# Other Languages but no other page >> (Homepage)
RewriteRule ^(fr|ar)?$ index.php?lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(fr|ar)/?$ index.php?lang=$1
# Other pages DEFAULT is >> ENGLISH
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?lang=en&alias=$2
# Other pages BUT ENGLISH
RewriteRule ^en/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ $1.php?lang=en&alias=$2
# Other Languages Other pages
RewriteRule ^(fr|ar)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ $2.php?lang=$1&alias=$3
```

Any help please?

Comment: What exactly is not working properly?

Comment: https://example.com/ar/ (css not loading correctly when add slash in the end)

Comment: also https://example.com/ar/news (dont work without slash) and when using slash no css loaded